# How can I use local push notifications in iOS 3.0?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, ios3.0

I want to use local push notification in iOS 3.0. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, local push notifications are an iOS 4 feature. Sorry.

**Update:** You could implement some of the local push notification features by using remote notifications. You would have to implement a service on a server that mimics the local push notification feature set. Have a look at [urbanairship.com](http://urbanairship.com/), they have services that allow you to schedule notifications for later delivery. This would mimic some of the local push notification features.

Comment: Then how can i implement this feature for io3.0 .Should i use remote ?

Comment: @Ali yes you should use remote notifications

Comment: provide some matterial for remote notifications plz

Answer (score 0):

Push notification are your only option.

They requires a network connection, a server of your own and are way more complicated to implement then local notification but are the only way to go in iOS 3.